# Uploading android symbols files to crashlytics not working anymore

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, crashlytics

I am trying to upload symbols files to crashlytics using this command:

```
firebase crashlytics:symbols:upload --app="ANDROID_APP_ID" /home/user/debuginfo/testApp/1.2.0+85
```

But i got this error:

> i  Generating symbols for /home/user/debuginfo/testApp/1.2.0+85
>
> ⚠ An unknown error occurred
>
> Error: java command failed with args:
> -jar,/home/user/.cache/firebase/crashlytics/buildtools/crashlytics-buildtools-2.9.2.jar,-symbolGenerator,breakpad,-symbolFileCacheDir,/tmp/crashlytics-e00e9d25-558c-410a-b516-03fbb119fd2b/nativeSymbols/ANDROID_APP_ID/breakpad,-verbose,-generateNativeSymbols,-unstrippedLibrary,/home/user/debuginfo/testApp/1.2.0+85,-clientName,firebase-cli;crashlytics-buildtools

Comment: Do you get the same error when trying to upload previos symbols that worked? What is the version you are using? "firebase crashlytics:symbols:upload --version "

Comment: @Gerardo i figure out that the problem is firebase tool did not find java command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is firebase tool did not find java command. so here is how i resolved the problem:

By updating environment variable in `.zshrc` file with these lines

```
export JAVA_HOME="/snap/android-studio/current/android-studio/jre"
export PATH="$PATH:/snap/android-studio/current/android-studio/jre/bin"
```

then i run this command:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

after that `firebase crashlytics:symbols:upload` run without error.

Comment: really helpful actually

Comment: Thanks GNassro, I hate them from google firebase who unable to print right error cause message (I even tried to run command with `--debug` flag). They even didn't say in [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli) that Java should be installed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In my case, after I opened firebase CLI as administrator (right click=> "Run as administrator) it fixed the problem.