# How to upload a mapping.txt file to Crashlytics using firebase-cli?

Tags: android, proguard, crashlytics, firebase-tools

I don't want to use [non-free](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1350) firebase gradle-plugin in my Android-project.

How to upload `mapping.txt` using [`firebase-cli`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#crashlytics-commands)?

I tried to execute this command:

```
firebase crashlytics:mappingfile:upload --app=[MY_APP_ID] \
    --resource-file=app/src/main/res/values/crashlytics.xml \
    mapping.txt
```

It gives me:

```
i  Uploading mapping file: mapping.txt
⚠  An unknown error occurred

Error: java command failed with args: -jar,/home/[...]/.cache/firebase/crashlytics/buildtools/crashlytics-buildtools-2.9.2.jar,-uploadMappingFile,mapping.txt,-resourceFile,/home/[...]/app/src/main/res/values/crashlytics.xml,-googleAppId,[MY_APP_ID],-verbose,-clientName,firebase-cli;crashlytics-buildtools

Having trouble? Try firebase [command] --help
```

If I add `--debug` flag I get almost the same output:

```
[2024-03-01T21:29:01.961Z] Buildtools Jar already downloaded at /home/[...]/.cache/firebase/crashlytics/buildtools/crashlytics-buildtools-2.9.2.jar
i  Uploading mapping file: mapping.txt 

Error: java command failed with args: -jar,/home/[...]/.cache/firebase/crashlytics/buildtools/crashlytics-buildtools-2.9.2.jar,-uploadMappingFile,mapping.txt,-resourceFile,/home/[...]/app/src/main/res/values/crashlytics.xml,-googleAppId,[MY_APP_ID],-verbose,-clientName,firebase-cli;crashlytics-buildtools

Having trouble? Try firebase [command] --help
```

Previously I've installed `firebase-cli` on my remote server using this command:

```
curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash
```

And made all necessary steps after typing:

```
firebase login
```

Is there an option to find out the cause of the error?

Running another command `crashlytics:mappingfile:generateid` gives me the same error message.

Comment: What do you mean by "non-free firebase gradle-plugin"?  It's closed source, but it's totally free to use.

Comment: I mean "free" as in "free speech", not as in "free beer":) When I use closed source software I don't feel myself "free":)

Comment: In the United States, "free speech" is a right that allows individuals to express their thoughts and ideas without persecution.  It has nothing to do with software.  Maybe you meant "free software" as expressed by the goals of the [Free Software Foundation](https://www.fsf.org/)?

Comment: I can't find source code of firebase crashlytics gradle plugin, that's why I think it is [proprietary (or non-free) software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proprietary_software). Correct me if I am wrong and there is source code somewhere. Anyway, my question is about `firebase-cli`, do you know how to use it?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74788376

Answer (score 0):

`Firebase-cli` uses java under the hood, check if java installed on your machine:

```bash
java -version
```

If this command fails, install java and try to run your commands again.